# Installing PHP enxtension pecl_http in xampp windows 8

Tags: php, windows, http, xampp, pecl

Need help installing PECL_http to my exsting php in xamp windows. Tried following code:
**pecl install pecl_http**

but i get following error:

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pecl_http" install
>   failed

Please help me providing step by step guide for installing pecl_http 1.7.6 extension.

Thanks $ Regards
-Nisarg

Comment: DL manually: http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/2.5.0rc1/

Comment: Do you fix this issue?